# 'and' and 'in' during json iteration

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

Using python 2.7 and I'm trying to check if a key is in the jason and if the value of that key matches the value of a query.

I'm doing the following which, at first seems pretty standard:

```
for key, value in fields.iteritems():
    if key == 'field_1' and value in my_array:
        print key, value
```

The program doesn't go beyond `if key == 'field_1'` - I looked at the documentation but I couldn't find anything that helped... it just seems like this should work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the contents of your JSON?

Comment: This *should work*. As an aside, instead of iterating over your `fields` `dict`, you could do `'field_1' in fields and fields['field_1'] in my_array`, taking advantage of short-circuiting...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga your suggestion worked... I'm puzzled!

Comment: @Gorgorita32Gorgorita then that's *very* strange indeed, since your iteration approach should work just the same. Can you show us the json?